# Confused between marked price , selling price , cost price

Tags: arithmetic

By selling an article at 20% discount off the marked price , a shop keeper still makes 10% profit on his cost . If cost price is $1200 , calculate the marked price of the article .

I learned that marked price is the "base price" on an item before any discount is given.

From my understanding of the definition, marked price and cost price must be the same then? But it's not the same , so what's the difference ?

Selling price is the price after discount have been given and this price is what people have to pay to buy the item ?

Pls help... Thanks ..

Comment: Say I make an object for $100 $(I mean, that's what the materials and labor cost).  I mark it for sale at $150$  but ultimately I sell it for $140$.  Then the cost price is $100$, the marked price is $150$, and the sale price is $140$. the realized profit is sale price - cost, or $140-100=40$.

Answer (score 2):

Let S, M and C stand for selling , market  and cost prize.

0) C = 1200

1)S = 80% of M, I.e. S = (8/10)M.

2) Profit : 10% of Cost, I.e. P = (1/10) 1200 = 120.

S = C + Profit = 1320, and this gives using 1):

S = (8/10)M = 1320, solve for M:

M = (10/8) 1320 = 13 200/8 = 1650.

Answer (score 1):

80%×C.P + C.P = S.P
0.8× 1200 + 1200 =$3360 which is my Selling Price.

This S.P represents only 80% because l got a 20%discount.
If l didn't get a discount, then I would have had to pay the full 100% which would be my marked price.

Since          80%      =3360
Therefore  100%    =M.P
Cross multiply   0.8 × MP=1×3360 
Therefore the marked price is 3360÷0.8 = $4200

Comment: Wow, that's off by more than a factor of two. There are mistakes not only in the first formula but also in the arithmetic on the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1200}{80} \times 110=1650$  which is marked price  here we add $10$ in $100$ because  of $10\%$ profit and reduce $20$ from $100$ because of $20\%$ discount